# Test connection a un SPARQL Endpoint

Tags: grails

Comunidad:
Recientemente he estado trabajando en el desarrollo de un webapp en grails, y necesito agregar la funcionalidad "Test Connection" para ver si una URL que es insertada corresponde con un SPARQL Endpoint con datos, ya validé con una expresión regular que la URL termine en "sparql o query", sin embargo me gustaria adicionarle la funcionalidad para que pruebe la conexión. Gracias por adelantado.